# How do I INSERT binary data from a local file with SQLCMD?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I need to insert binary data from a file into a varbinary(max) column in SQL Server as a part of my deployment script.

The file is on the local machine, SQL Server is on the remote.

Here is the data table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Config] (
    [ID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Cfg]  VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

I need something like this pseudo-command

```
INSERT INTO Config(ID, Name, Cfg) VALUES (0, 'Default', ????('Default.cfg')??? )
```

i.e. data is taken from a local file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Whatever else you do, you'll almost certainly have to copy the file to the server, or expose it through a network share from the client machine. Basically, whatever you enter through SQLCMD (except, specifically, for the "GO" command), is sent to the server as a blob of text, and executed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can insert and update binary data into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field with sqlcmd by using `OPENROWSET()` pointing to path of file. Do note the file path cannot be dynamically concatenated or passed as a parameter but hard coded as is.

**T-SQL** *(save as .sql script)*

```
USE mydatabase;
GO

INSERT INTO Config ([ID], [Name], [Cfg]) VALUES (0, 'Default', 
    (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Path\To\Default.cfg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS CFG_FILE));

UPDATE Config SET [Cfg] =
    (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Path\To\Default.cfg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS CFG_FILE)
WHERE ID = 0;
GO
```

**sqlcmd** *(command line)*

```
sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\Path\To\myScript.sql
```

Comment: Curious, why the downvote? This has been tested on SQL Server 2017 for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Google 'SQL BULK INSERT' that can get you at least some insertion from files, though it is meant for multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

By all means this is not possible with SQLCMD alone.

A more powerful deployment tool is needed here.